# What is the most appropriate data type for latitude/longitude in Realm for React Native?

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm trying to determine what the most optimal choice is for a Realm object schema that needs to store latitude and longitude properties.

From my understanding, the ideal data type (if I was using something like swift) would be a signed number datatype with a precision of 6.

It does not appear that the precision of the number can be controlled from React Native, which is to be expected since its mapped to a Javascript object, but it is still not clear to me as to what the appropriate choice is.

From the Realm documentation for React Native:

> int, float, and double properties map to JavaScript Number objects. Internally ‘int’ and ‘double’ are stored as 64 bits while float is stored with 32 bits.

[Realm Docs - Basic property types](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#basic-property-types)

I assume that `float` ist the correct choice but it's not clear to me that this is the right answer. Any thoughts from someone experienced with how realm handles these datatypes is much appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the docs, I would say that it can handle a `double`. In our system we use `double`(but it's WPF with ESRI for the map, which is a different case), since it usually allows for more precise results. I think it boils down the what map framework you're using

Comment: Thank you for the comment - that makes sense but possibly for my purposes Float would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Float` is the right choice. 32 bits are sufficient to store latitude and longitude and it will be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you - that does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I need to round to 3 decimal places. I found that `Float` caused rounding errors, but `Double` is now working with expected precision.